# can't get a full list of name from a multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json, output

[image: Example data]

API data, 
Here is my code trying to get a full list of name from the above arrays:

```
<?php
    $url = "www.com" ;
    $str= file_get_contents($url);
    $arr = json_decode($str,true);

   for($i=1; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
      echo $arr["data"][$i]["name"];
   };
?>
```

but I can only get the first name "Jonia", not all:(

Anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: or, you could do `$listOfNames = array_column($arr["data"], "name");`

Comment: You are specifying the wrong key your $i will never get till 27

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access each key with value `1`, `27`, `52`, ... which is not in sequence. So, what you can do is get the keys of the `data` object and then loop through each key of that object like `$arr["data"]['1']["name"]`, `$arr["data"]['27']["name"]` and so on.

```
<?php
  $url = "www.com" ;
  $str= file_get_contents($url);
  $arr = json_decode($str,true);

  foreach($arr["data"] as $key=>$val){
    echo $arr["data"][$key]["name"];
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
for($i=1; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
   echo $arr["data"][$i]["name"];
};
```

I would use PHP's built in [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
$listOfNames = array_column($arr["data"], "name");
```

which would do exactly what you'd like and gather a list of names for you in an array.

Alternatively, you could loop through the code with a `foreach()`:

```
foreach($arr["data"] as $val){
    echo $val;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Derek. Your code also can work me out. Thanks again :)))

Comment: @MaTis no problem!